# Can not deserialize instance of PaymentResponse[] out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

unable to read response using jackson objectmapper. getting out of START_OBJECT token. Here is the input json and error message.  PaymentResponse java pojo is common code which I don't have access to add any annotations. Any help in adding deserialization configuration ?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PaymentResponse[] paymentResponse  = objectMapper.readValue(serverResponseStr, PaymentResponse[].class);

{
    "PaymentResponse[]": [
        {
            "uid": "111",
            "name": "kiran"
        },
        {
            "uid": "112",
            "name": "kumar"
        }
    ]
}

Can not deserialize instance of PaymentResponse[] out of START_OBJECT token

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of PaymentResponse[] out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"PaymentResponse[]": [{"uid": "111","name": "kiran"},{"uid": "112","name": "kumar"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal would be if you could change the response to something like:

```
[{
        "uid": "111",
        "name": "kiran"
    }, {
        "uid": "112",
        "name": "kumar"
    }
]
```

If you can't change it, then please try this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
JsonNode array = objectMapper.readValue(anotherResponseStr, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode paymentResponse = array.get("PaymentResponse[]");

List<PaymentResponse> p = objectMapper.readValue(paymentResponse.toString(), 
typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, PaymentResponse.class));
```